# Get ImageView Image Original Size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `TableViewCell` with an `ImageView`, and I am setting the image like so:

```
[self.contentImageView setImageWithURL:thumbnail_url];
```

The `contentMode` is set to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`, and the subviews are clipped.
This works best for images that are either Portrait or Landscape, but `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` actually works better for Landscape images, which are far more plentiful.

So, I want to detect the orientation of the image by comparing the width and height, and change the `contentMode` accordingly.

At first, I tried to inspect/log the `ImageView.image` property, directly after I set it from the url, but it show's nil. *not sure why exactly...?*

Next, I decided to put that `NSURL` into an `NSData` object, then create an `UIImage` from that data, and set the `ImageView`'s image property with that iVar, like so:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:thumbnail_url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
[self.contentImageView setImage:image];
// Get image.size etc.
```

This - particularly the `NSData` call - slows down the loading of the `TableViewCell's` considerably, so I'd like to avoid it.

So, I'm wondering if there is anyway to reach into the *un-cropped* source image properties of the `ImageView` before the scaling happens to the `contentMode`?

Comment: Do you use AFNetworking? I ask because you call the function "setImageWithURL".
If yes, did you try this method "- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure;" and print image.size when you are in the "success" block?

Comment: @jregnauld yes, this method is part of AFNetworking - sorry, just noticed this (not my original code) ... will try that method out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is your misunderstanding of how that first method works. `setImageWithURL:` is a method from one of the open source image loading libraries. Probably either [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

These methods are asynchronous and return immediately. They download the image on a background queue and then return to the main queue to set up the view with it. You are trying to access the `image` before it is downloaded. The reason the manual `NSData` approach is working is because it is synchronous and the main queue is stuck while the images download.

Both libraries I mentioned have separate methods with a callback block on the main queue allowing you to act on the response.

For AFNetworking you can use this method:

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure;
```

For SDWebImage you can use this method:

```
- (void)sd_setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url completed:(SDWebImageCompletionBlock)completedBlock;
```

In either of these, the callback blocks will let you access the image once it is downloaded (if successful).

You can also make something like this work manually using the `dataWithContentsOfURL:` approach by using GCD like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^()
               {
                   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:thumbnail_url];
                   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^()
                                  {
                                      [self.contentImageView setImage:image];
                                  });
               });
```

This is a basic pattern used in networking to perform the network request and processing on a background queue before updating the view on the main queue. Keep in mind this particular piece of code is very simplistic and would require more work to work as nicely as the libraries I mentioned above.

Comment: thanks for your answer... yes, I am using both of those libraries in my project 0 didn't realize that this call was part of the AFNetworking library at first... will look into the Async methods and try and do what I need to do in the success block...

Comment: that did the trick, thanks! should have looked at the superclass - just assumed it was basic UIKit... and yeah, upon reflection, the (a-)synchronous nil of the image makes sense...